# python libjpeg8d installation issue

Tags: python-2.7, computer-vision, deep-learning, shared-libraries, libjpeg

Hello I am trying to install libjpeg-8d library (http://archive.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs-museum/snapshot-20121101/blfs-20121102/general/libjpeg.html) inside my python 2.7 virtual environment to run the python script https://github.com/tkarras/progressive_growing_of_gans/blob/master/h5tool.py

I installed the required version of the libraries for above script.(Specifically Pillow version 3.1.1)
I am hitting the line https://github.com/tkarras/progressive_growing_of_gans/blob/master/h5tool.py#L508  where the md5 hash generated by my library seems to be different from the expected hash value.

I have installed the libjpeg-8d library and updated my PATH env variable to look for the libjpeg.so.8.4 shared object.
I am wondering if I am missing something obvious to ensure that if the correct shared object is used or not. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the LD_LIBRARY_PATH of the shared library is not pointing to the path where you have libjpeg library ? 
Try updating your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the path where you have libjpeg8.so installed.

Satwik

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem generating CelebAHQ datasets,perhaps you will have to download appropriate folder in CelebA. I had same problem when I downloaded aligned imaged folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).